# Relative path of a given file from a service application in Delphi

Tags: delphi, path, windows-services, relative-path

I have a problem loading a file, as I'm passing a relative path to the function `FileExists(Filename: String)` and it's returning false, that is, it does not find the file in the directory that I pass.

I have a file named `Template.html` in the `D:\Programming\Delphi\Projects\SendMail` directory, and a service written in Delphi whose `.EXE` is in the `D:\Programming\Delphi\Automation` directory. I am passing the relative path: `.\..\Projects\SendMail\Template.html` to `FileExists()`, but it's returning that the file does not exist.

I think that has something to do with the relative path of a service and the relative path of the application being different. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: I have an insight, people here won't like a question asked in spanish.

Comment: In Ingles, por favor. 

Seriously, English might help a lot in getting your question answered :)

ps: I think you are launching it from the wrong directory. Try specifying the full path, as in \Programming\Delphi\...

Answer (score 8):

As lorenzog said, try specifying the full path.

You can also try to set the currentdir to your likings.

```
//sets currentdir to your application.exe dir
SetCurrentDir(ExtractFileDir(ParamStr(0)));
```

Answer (score 3):

You assume that the current directory of the service is the directory the executable is stored in. Call GetCurrentDir to find out the current directory.

Comment: Ok, I just found the directory: C:\Windows\system32\. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

My experience has been that services start with a working folder of `%SystemRoot%\System32` no matter where the actual executable is located.

The way that I have got around this limitation is to write a registry key during installation of the service (e.g. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\MyCompany\MyApp\INSTALL_PATH`) that points to what I would *like* the working folder to be.  Then when the service starts, it grabs the data from the registry and uses that value as the base when creating paths to files.